# Will this 'Where' condition speed up SQL query

Tags: sql, where-clause

I am going to be making a complex (for me) SQL query that involves finding the totals of both invoiced value and goods received value both linked to a purchase order line (so that's 3 joined tables, and possibly more) along with various date filters and so on.
In many cases, PO lines will reach a state where I know I won't ever have to worry about them again. I could therefore add a logic field to my PO line table to show this, tick the relevant lines as I go along, and add a `where` condition in the SQL to make it ignore them.

What I want to know is, will that Where condition be executed before or after the Select? Because if it's doing all the calcs and then just filtering the output, I don't want it as it's just more time/processing. If however the Where clause filters the input (ie before it does any calcs) then it could be a very significant time-saver.

I know you could just say 'try it and see' but whether or not I add that logic field has implications for other processes and reports, so I want to get it planned without spending too much time building a test.

So, the **TL;DR: Is `Where` executed before `Select` in SQL?** Or to put it another way, does `Where` filter the input or the output of a query?

Hope that makes sense, I'm still a bit of a beginner here!

Comment: Without a query, database, sample data, and desired results, there is almost no information with which to formulate an answer.

Comment: Logically, the WHERE clause filter the FROM clause result. In practice, who knows - trust the dbms optimizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Order of execution](https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution) which shows that the `WHERE` clause is evaluated in step 2, while `SELECT` is step 5.

So the `WHERE` filters (and thus reduces) the number of rows that will be processed by the `SELECT`.

I'm not entirely sure if this applies to all regular SQL-based database engines - the site doesn't seem to limit itself to a single RDBMS - so there's a chance this will be handled the same by any relational database system